# android:onClick doesn't work with Android 4.0.3

Tags: android, menuitem

I've a strange problem with a simple view in Android API 15. In this view I've a simple menu with 2 menu items.
This code works fine with other Android API but not in this phone with Android 4.0.3:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/root_menu"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Help">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_about"
                android:onClick="aboutDialog"
                android:showAsAction="never"
                android:title="About"/>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

This is the Activity

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);
    }

    /**
     * Crea l'action bar
     *
     * @param menu
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_actionbar, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Apertura del dialog box con le informazioni sulla versione del programma
     *
     * @param v
     */
    public void aboutDialog(MenuItem v) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Test")
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // User cancelled the dialog
                    }
                });
        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        builder.create().show();
    }
}
```

So nothing strange in this code. But when I try to run on the device I've this exception:

```java
android.view.InflateException: Couldn't resolve menu item onClick handler 
    aboutDialog in class android.view.ContextThemeWrapper

        at android.view.MenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.<init>   (MenuInflater.java:202)
        at android.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.setItem(MenuInflater.java:402)
        at android.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.addItem(MenuInflater.java:436)
        at android.view.MenuInflater.parseMenu(MenuInflater.java:173)
        at android.view.MenuInflater.parseMenu(MenuInflater.java:151)
        at android.view.MenuInflater.inflate(MenuInflater.java:95)
        at 
        it.mobile.activity.home.HomeActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(HomeActivity.java:38)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2444)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:388)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:739)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:2833)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: aboutDialog 
 [interface android.view.MenuItem]
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
        at android.view.MenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.<init>
```

But I don't understand where is the problem. With another device all works fine!

Comment: Because of the Parameter, in your aboutDialog Method you have a parameter MenuItem and only with onclick it wont work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how to solve it with just xml.
From code perspective you will have to implement
     `public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`
 and then depending on the menu item call the required handler.

Answer (score 3):

Although this is out of date, here is the reason for the exception. When you look into the sources of android API 15 (4.0.3-4.0.4) in the class MenuInflator you will see this method:

```
public InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener(Context context, String methodName) {
mContext = context;
Class<?> c = context.getClass();
try {
    mMethod = c.getMethod(methodName, PARAM_TYPES);
} catch (Exception e) {
    InflateException ex = new InflateException(
            "Couldn't resolve menu item onClick handler " + methodName +
            " in class " + c.getName());
    ex.initCause(e);
    throw ex;
}
```

This is were the exception happens. As we see the method tries to find the Callback method on the class of the context item passed. So instead of calling `getMenuInflator()` in `onCreateOptionsMenu` you should call `new MenuInflator(this)`, so that `this` is passed as a context and then the code will work.

Another bug fix was to remove the theme from the manifest and i am still very puzzeled why that works. But well, it's just a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issues and I found this here -https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62795

```
    This is affecting Android 5.0 when applying the android:theme attribute.


        <Button
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onLoginEmail"

Clicking on the button throws
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onLoginEmail(View) in the activity class android.view.ContextThemeWrapper for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3994)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: onLoginEmail [class android.view.View]
            at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:664)
            at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:643)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3987)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
            />
```

I got around it by removing `android:theme` from the `TextView`